# PostgreSQL query selection in MapServer is not working?

Tags: postgresql, mapserver

When I make a selection in the query in Mapserver I got a blank page.

The query I use is: 
DATA "geom from (select * from bagmutlijst_201210.vo_gepland_gemeente where gemcode = '0141') as selection using unique gemcode using srid=28992"

The data is correct because if you use the following query (without a selection) I got a correct map.
DATA 'geom from bagmutlijst_201210.vo_gepland_gemeente using unique gemcode using srid=28992'

Why is the selection not working?

Answer (score 1):

There wan't anything wrong with the query, but what the mapserver request I did. The polygon I selected was outside the BBOX.

When I changed the BBOX the polygon was visible.